# How to 'Skip' to Next Row in For Each Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am looping through a 2D range object using `For Each`. By default this loops through columns and then rows. I have a check in a column that indicates whether I should process the row or not. What I am finding is that even if I am not meant to process the row, the program still loops through each column in the given range row - which is hugely inefficient.

Image of an example data set:

[image]

Current code:

```vb
Sub ForEachLoop()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myRng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim strCheck As String
    

    Set myRng = Selection 'COLUMN F:G IN IMAGE

    For Each cell In myRng
        strCheck = ws.Range("E" & cell.Row).Value
        If strCheck = "PROCESS" Then
            'do something
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I would like to know if there is a way to move to the next row in the range instead of looping through each column in that row. The `For` loop needs to remain within the `For Each` loop because I am doing colour formatting on cells.

Comment: Loop through the rows, then the cells within each row: `For each rw in myRng.Rows` then you can test the value before you process each cell in that row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two loops: loop the rows, do the check, then loop the cells in the row.

```
Dim rw As Range
For Each rw in myRng.Rows
   strCheck = ws.Range("E" & rw.Row).Value

   If strCheck = "PROCESS" Then
       Dim cell As Range
       For Each cell in rw.Cells
          'process
       Next
   End If   
Next
```

Comment: Thanks @BigBen, how would I refer to the row for `rw` to set `strCheck`? Would it be `strCheck = ws.Range("E" & rw.Row).Value`?

Comment: @Dean yes, sorry, fixed.

Comment: I am getting a type mismatch error when using `Debug.Print cell.Value` within the second `For` loop. Can you use the `.Value` property in this manner?

Comment: @Dean - try `For Each cell in rw.Cells` (sorry again).